# Set, pick up and check a Cookie after a video (YouTube API) finish - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, video, cookies, youtube-api

I need the browser to understand when a user saw a YouTube video (YouTube API) to the end and record that, but all client-side. But even though I already have the function that recognizes the end of the video, I can not use and fire other functions inside it (nested function). I am using Javascript.

**Below the code so far:**

```
    //[Interações]

    // criar player youtube 
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        width: '796',
        height: '448',
        videoId: 'jyPOVbww6fU',
        playerVars: {
         'showinfo': 0,
         'rel': 0
       },
       events: {
        onReady: onPlayerReady,
        onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // função ao terminar o vídeo
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
      if(event.data === 0) {

        //Set, Pick and Read Cookie

        function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
          var d = new Date();
          d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
          var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
          document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
        }

        function getCookie(cname) {
          var name = cname + "=";
          var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
          var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
          for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
              c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
              return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
          }

function checkCookie() {
  var cookieVideo = getCookie("video1");
  if (cookieVideo != "") {
    console.log('Cookie ON');
  } else {
    console.log('Cookie OFF');
    cookieVideo = "visto"
    if (cookieVideo != "" && cookieVideo != null) {
      setCookie("video1", cookieVideo, 30);
      console.log('Cookie ON');
    }
  }
}

    //[Desabilitar Menu]

  jQuery(document).on('contextmenu', function() {
    return false;
  });
```